# Cakephp 3 CSV export Plugin Issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, export-to-csv

I am trying to use [FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview) in Cakephp 3. I am trying several time given instruction but its not working. below error message is showing

[image]

can anyone give me step by step guideline for this. it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

For your reference please see the below link

https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to ask for tutorials. Please check the [Asking Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for an explanation regarding what's on-topic for SO. That being said, when receiving errors, please always post the _complete_, _exact_ error message, and include the related code!

Comment: Maybe you can look into the sandbox code @ http://sandbox3.dereuromark.de/sandbox/csv - There it works and the code is publically accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It is the best solution for creating csv or excel sheet using php. You will find a cakephp helper for creating csv/excel document using PHPExcel .